# Making git forget I did anything to a file

Tags: git

Theres a file I may have accidentally changed in my branch, which I have committed to and rebased several times. Before I hand over this branch to somebody else, I want to make git forget I have ever done anything to this file.

How do I ask git to get the latest version of that file from the master branch (which other people have been updating), and forget the fact that my branch ever touched that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easiest to checkout the file from master, to overwrite your changes. After you commit the file that you just checked out, you may wish to rebase/squash the branch to remove any commits made to that file. The syntax to checkout would be:

```
git checkout origin/master <path_to_file>
```

A more advanced option may be to use [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

Answer (score 3):

When on your branch, you can checkout the file from `master`:

```
git checkout master the_file
```

Commit that change and then find the sha1 of the commit where you accidentally changed the file. And use

```
git rebase -i that_sha1
```

You will see a list of commits from your branch, from oldest to newest. Move the last line (the fixing commit you just made) after the first line (the incorrect commit) and change `pick` to `fixup`. This will have the same effect as amending the incorrect commit and then rebasing the rest of commits on top of that.

This all assumes you didn't publish your branch. If you did and somebody else has it now too, you are in trouble.

Comment: This answer definitely seems more correct, but the Sean's one is a lot lot simpler (for a git noob) and seems to have done the job for me (git diff --name-only'ing against master does not show the offending file anymore and i don't exist in that file's git blame)... 
because you seem to know a lot of git magic, can you comment on when (or why) your answer is the better thing to do?

Comment: If I understand Sean's solution correctly, the incorrect file would stay in the history and you are going to have one commit that changes it back to the correct version. That's a reasonable thing to do, but you said you want it look like you never did anything to the file. You can't achieve that without rebasing or branch-filtering.

Comment: yes.. so i rebased... 
after i do a master checkout, and rebase that with all previous commits, does the rebased branch still remember having changed and then unchanged that file?

Comment: That depends on whether you rebased it correctly. Look into the history and check for yourself.